# ls command and age of files

Tags: bash, shell, ls

I'm observing a directory with several log files. What I'm interested in, are files which have changed in say last 10 mins.

Is it possible to list all files in a directory older than n-minutes with a simple command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called *find*

```
find . -mmin +10
```

should do it.  See *man find* for more options.

Comment: I'd say this is not exactly right, there should be `+10` or `-10` (I never know which one), this form returns only files that changed _exactly_ 10 minutes in the past.

Comment: Have corrected it.  For some reason was thinking that "mmin" stood for modified minimum and thus it would mean modified at minimum 10 minutes ago.  Guess I should have taken my own advice and read the man page... :)

Comment: Modified minutes, I'd say. I always use `-mtime` so that I can use any units and so that I am forced to specify them not to create confusion.